# Subtituição de caracteres especiais por códigos ASCII

Tags: php, html, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou arrumando um site construível em *charset* ISO e quando passo para UTF-8 os caracteres especiais aparecem na tela com aquele losango e um ponto de interrogação, então além de trocar de *charset* estou precisando trocar os caracteres pelos códigos ASCII.

```
Ex: á - &aacute;
    é - &eacute;
...
```

Como posso fazer isso de forma uma forma mais rápida? Alguma função em PHP?

Comment: uma solução intermediária seria por isso no começo do PHP: `declare(encoding='ISO-8859-1');` enquanto vai arrumando.

Comment: você tem os sources já com o problema? Uma solução também poderia ser substituição em massa com um bom editor de código, mas é relativamente perigoso. Se for só fazer conversão para a tela, pode usar a solução do Antonio. Se você der mais detalhes na questão, ajuda.

Comment: Estou colocando algumas opções, não sei se entendi totalmente o que você precisa.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Se eu entendi o que você quer tem uma função pronta para isto, é a [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Se você quer mudar isto no fonte do HTML, pode fazer um *script* rápido para processar todos arquivos usando esta função.

Também tem diversos utilitários para fazer isto, inclusive [on-line](http://www.web2generators.com/html/entities).

Dependendo do editor que você está usando ele tem como fazer isto em alguma opção ou no momento de salvar.

Além disto pode usar o que o Bacco comentou [`declare(encoding='ISO-8859-1');`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php) em cada arquivo do PHP, estabelecendo uma diretiva para a geração correta do HTML.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado @bigown